# Expresión regular para capturar un dato en base a salto de línea

Tags: regex

Tengo que capturar unos datos de unos documentos legales que vienen en el siguiente formato:

```
REPRESENTANTE LEGAL
PEREZ NARIÑO WILLIAM
```

En el ejemplo, viene con un salto de línea y quisiera saber si existe una expresión regular que pueda hacer salto de linea en base a la palabra "REPRESENTANTE LEGAL" y poder capturar el dato "PEREZ NARIÑO WILLIAM" por ejemplo.

Comment: Ya probaste preg_replace("/[\nREPRESENTANTE LEGAL]+/","CARACTER_REEMPLAZO",$TXT)? sALUDOS :)

Comment: Hola @RubenHernandez No le veo mucho sentido a esa expresión regular. Además OP quería buscar, no reemplazar.

Comment: Por favor, especifica el lenguaje de programación o herramienta que estás utilizando

Comment: Por favor, especifica si entre REPRESENTANTE LEGAL y el nombre, el número de saltos de línea puede ser variable. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta expresión regular hace lo que indicas: `[^\r\n]+`. Lo unico que tienes que hacer es obtener el segundo valor del array generado, por ejemplo en JS sería:

```js
var texto = "REPRESENTANTE LEGAL\nPEREZ NARIÑO WILLIAM";
var nombre = texto.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
console.log(nombre[1]);
```

Saludos!

Comment: Fallaría si en el string tuviera más datos. Por ejemplo: `Nombre<\n>Pepito<\n>Representante legal<\n>Juan`. En el enunciado se especifica que la búsqueda del dato debe depender del string `REPRESENTANTE LEGAL`

Comment: Entiendo que esto genera un array `nombre` con tantos elementos como líneas tenga el texto. Por tanto, el ejemplo que da @Julio tendría `nombre = ["Nombre", "Pepito", "Representante legal", "Juan"]`

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con lo siguiente: Buscará líneas después de "REPRESENTANTE LEGAL", ignorando todos los posibles espacios y saltos de línea que hubiera en medio.

```js
var texto = `

REPRESENTANTE LEGAL
  

PEREZ NARIÑO WILLIAM

`;
var regex = /\bREPRESENTANTE\s+LEGAL\s+(.+)\s*/i;

// Sólo nos interesa el primer grupo de captura
var nombre = regex.exec(texto)[1];

console.log(nombre);
```

Si pudieras tener más de una vez "REPRESENTANTE LEGAL", añade el modificador `g`a la expresión regular. Así: `/\bREPRESENTANTE\s+LEGAL\s+(.+)\s*/ig`

El modificador `i` hace la búsqueda ignorando las mayúsculas/minúsculas. Es decir, podrías encontrar "representante legal" (en minúsculas) Si no es lo que quieres, quita el modificador `i`

En php sería algo así.

```
<?php
$re = '/\bREPRESENTANTE\s+LEGAL\s+(.+)\s*/m';
$str = '
REPRESENTANTE LEGAL


PEREZ NARIÑO WILLIAM

';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

print($matches[0][1]);
```

De igual manera, en el ejemplo de php solo estaba imprimiendo la primera ocurrencia. Si hubiera más de una ocurrencia (más de un string "representante legal") deberías recorrer el array `$matches` y para cada elementos imprimir el primer grupo de captura

Ten en cuenta que cuando se hace una pregunta sobre expresiones regulares, conviene aclarar qué lenguaje de programación o utilidad estás utilizando.

Explicación de la expresión regular:

```
\b  # Puedes considerarlo como 'inicio de palabra', de esta manera
    # encontrarás REPRESENTANTE pero no "PREPRESENTANTE"
REPRESENTANTE
\s+            # 1 o más espacios (incluye saltos de línea)
LEGAL
\s+            # 1 o más espacios (incluye saltos de línea)
(.+)           # .+ significa cualquier caracter salvo salto de línea
               # 1 o más veces. Lo metemos en un grupo de captura ()
\s*            # 0 o más espacios (por si el nombre termina con espacios
               # , así no los metemos en el grupo de captura)
```

Comment: Sería interesante qu eindicaras qué hacen los flags "g", "m" e "i".

Comment: @fedorqui Hecho! He quitado el modificador `m` ya que no era necesario. Los demás están explicados.

Comment: `\s` también afecta al salto de línea? Pensé que solo espacios y tabs

Comment: Sí, `\s` procesa tanto espacios horizontales (`\h`) como espacios verticales (`\v`) Los saltos de línea están incluidos en éstos últimos.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoro en qué lenguaje estás trabajando, por lo que ofrezco una expresión regular desligada de lenguaje pero dependiente de que el lenguaje ofrezca *look behinds*.

Lo que puedes escribir es algo así como:

```
(?<=REPRESENTANTE LEGAL\n)[^\n]+
```

Aquí utilizamos un *positive lookbehind*. Lo que está haciendo es decirle al motor de expresiones regulares que busque el texto "REPRESENTANTE LEGAL" seguido de un salto de línea y coja lo que viene en la línea siguiente (hasta que se encuentra un nuevo salto de línea).

Lo puedes ver explicado y con ejemplos en https://regex101.com/r/coiH3H/3

Comment: Creo que no está desligada del lenguaje, por ejemplo no funcionaría con javascript, ya que no soporta lookbehinds (o al menos no en todos los navegadores). Por otro lado, no queda muy claro el número de saltos de línea entre representante legal y el nombre, ni si éstos pueden ser variables. En el post original había dos saltos de línea, pero ahora ha habido una edición reciente y hay solo uno.

Comment: @Julio buen comentario, gracias. Sobre los saltos de línea, yo hice la edición para mostrarlo en formato código, tal y como se suele hacer. Si el OP no hubiera puesto dos saltos, las dos líneas habrían salido juntas.

Comment: @Julio añadí `[^\n]+` en sustitución de `.*` para que coja solamente la siguiente línea.

Comment: Pido aclaración a OP :)

Comment: Creo que funciona exactamente igual que antes `.` y `[^\n]` son equivalente a menos que el modificador `s` esté habilitado